# Sounds Play on iOS Simulator but not on Published App

Tags: iphone, audio

I made an app that utilizes sounds, and it played them fine on the simulator and when I tested it on my iPhone, but when people download it from the App Store, the sounds don't play. Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: what is the file type? i believe if you use mp3 it will play in simulator but not on device

Comment: wav, it plays on simulator, and when I run the project on my device using the provisioning and all that stuff it plays, but people who download it from the store can't hear the sounds.

Comment: how many people? if its just one, it might be the dreaded mute button issue.

Comment: did you download it from the store and try it your self on your device?

Comment: yes same result as everybody else, no sound. The project I compiled straight from the computer plays sound but the project I downloaded from the store doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ipa file - are there the audio files? After that, You can also check if audio file has been added to the currently active target..